# "ng lint" is not picking up the "tslint.json" file for linting

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have newly created an angular application. Since it's the beginning, to follow and maintain good coding practices, I want to implement the linting. So, I created a new `tslint.json` file (it was not generated by default while running `ng new` command) and defined few rules in it.

But, when I am running `ng lint` command to check for linting errors, even if I have intentionally made a mistake, the linting is passing without any fail.

```
xyz % ng lint              

Linting "project"...

All files pass linting.
```

I believe `ng lint` command is not picking up the linting configuration file properly.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the newest Angular version? Angular no longer uses tslint. It is now using eslint. So you should have a eslint file somewhere

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest Angular. Are you talking about `.eslintrc.json` file?

Comment: yes exactly. So your ng lint should work properly

Comment: Ok, I added the same rules in `.eslintrc.json` file and it worked. Thanks!